# What is the recommended way of automating a task in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, automation

I'm still kind of new to Linux, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I need to copy all subdirectories and files from one directory to another ever 5 minutes or so, with the old data automatically being overwritten with the new data.

I'd also like this to run at startup. Is there any way this can be done? If so, what program would I need to schedule the automation and what is the command line I would need.

Comment: Also because it makes the site work better (that's the real reason..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do the actual copy with

```
rsync --archive --delete "fromdir/" "todir/"
```

This is going to be more efficient than using `cp`, since `rsync` only copies files that have changed, and even then only copies over the change itself, rather than the entire file.

If you prefer that it not delete files in `todir` that have been deleted in `fromdir`, you just leave out the `--delete` option.

The `--archive` option basically tells it to preserve the state of the files as well as their content.  Note that if you have any symbolic links in `dir1`, this will copy the *links* themselves, and **not** the files they link to.  Using this flag with `rsync` is similar to using `cp -a`.

Make sure you use the closing slash on `fromdir/`: this tells `rsync` to copy the *contents* of that directory, rather than the *directory itself*.  In other words, if you *leave out* the final `/`, you will end up with

```
todir/
todir/stuff
todir/fromdir/
todir/fromdir/morestuff
```

rather than

```
todir/
todir/morestuff
```

Comment: +1 for improving my answer!

Comment: +1 for cooperation!  Actually I can't, I already voted your answer up at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a script in cron, how to do this, read here: http://www.foogazi.com/2006/12/07/understand-cron-jobs-in-5-minutes/

Instead of a script, you could type a command to execute in your crontab, it would look like:

```
*/5 * * * * cp -r /fromdir /todir
```

also add to /etc/crontab the following line to exexute it at boot:

```
@reboot root cp -r /fromdir /todir
```